# DataAdapter.Update not doing so but suggesting is has

Tags: .net, ado.net, dataset

I'm moving data between SQL Server and a local SQL Server compact database. I'm populating a Dataset with a single table using standard DataAdapter.Fill etc. I then pass that dataset to another function which attemps to update the local SQL Compact DB.

So basically I want to extract a dataset with a single datatable (for now) from on DB (SQL Server) and throw it into another DB (SQL Compact).

(Yes I know there are tools to do this and sync framework there are other reasons for this approach)

To detect the changes I'm using a data version (of my own rolling) and an ID. So if the ID is > that the highest one we have then mark the row as Added, otherwise if the dataversion of the row is higher then mark the row as Changed.

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(row["SettingID"]) > id)
{
   row.AcceptChanges();
   row.SetAdded();
}
else if(Convert.ToInt32(row["DataVersion"]) > dv)
{
    row.AcceptChanges();
    row.SetModified();
```

}

Deletes are handled slightly differently which is not important here.

I then make an SqlCeAdapter to try and insert / update the records into the CE database.

```
using (SqlCeDataAdapter ad = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select * from " + tableName, Connection))
{
    using (SqlCeCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(ad))
    {
        cb.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges;
        ad.UpdateCommand = (SqlCeCommand)cb.GetUpdateCommand();
        ad.InsertCommand = (SqlCeCommand)cb.GetInsertCommand();

        ad.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source); //Tried both types and not doing this.

        ad.RowUpdating += ad_RowUpdating;
        ad.RowUpdated += ad_RowUpdated;

        int result = ad.Update(ds, tableName);
    }
}
```

For inserts this works fine - they all come through.

Updates do not work.

If I check the rows of the data table being passed in (i.e. just after the using statement above) they have a staus of changed which is correct. The Update method returns the correct number of rows to be updated but they have not changed (it lies!). There is no exception.

I subscribe to the RowUpdating and RowUpdated events and the RowUpdating method does fire for each row. When I look at the SqlCeRowUpdatedEventArgs each row has a status of SkipCurrentRow and the command object is null. The RowUpdated event never fires.

Why has the status of Modified been lost and SkipCurrentRow being used ?

If I modify this and create a destination dataset and update it with the rows from the source then both events fire and the updates do take place. Again no idea what the differences are. I've tried comparing the properties of both datasets and datatables and they seem identical.

I think this should be simple but its one of those forehead->desk interface situations.

Any ideas ?

Comment: An update - I noted that I can change the SkipCurrentRow status so I did to continue and get an error "update requires the command clone to be valid" - which I can't find a meaning for anywhere.

Comment: Have you had any success in finding a solution for this? I ask because I have a very similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885259/sqldataadapter-update-does-not-update-sql-table
And I would prefer not to have to load the destination table into memory to be able to update just some records.