# SqlDataAdapter.Update does not update SQL table

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm having some trouble getting some VB.NET code to update my MS SQL table.

In the real program the DataTable is read from a file as an xml-serialized DataTable, but I have reduced the problem code down to the following:

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim myConn As New SqlConnection("<myconnstring>")

        Dim myDA As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE 1=2", myConn)

        Dim myTable As New DataTable
        myDA.Fill(myTable)

        Dim myRow As DataRow

        myRow = myTable.NewRow
        myRow("IntField") = 4
        myRow("TextField") = "loik"
        myTable.Rows.Add(myRow)
        myRow.AcceptChanges()
        myRow.SetAdded()

        myRow = myTable.NewRow
        myRow("IntField") = 3
        myRow("TextField") = "poiuy"
        myTable.Rows.Add(myRow)
        myRow.AcceptChanges()
        myRow.SetModified()

        Dim myCB As New SqlCommandBuilder(myDA)
        ' My changes should overwrite whatever is already in the database
        myCB.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges

        Debug.Print(myCB.GetInsertCommand.CommandText)
        Debug.Print(myCB.GetUpdateCommand.CommandText)
        Debug.Print(myDA.Update(myTable))

    End Sub

End Module
```

Initially TestTable looks like this (IntField is the Primary Key on the table):

```
IntField    TextField
---------------------
1           qwert
2           asdfg
3           zxcvb
```

After I run the program TestTable looks like this:

```
IntField    TextField
---------------------
1           qwert
2           asdfg
3           zxcvb
4           loik
```

The new record (IntField = 4) is added correctly, BUT the updated record (IntField = 3) does not contain the new value in the TextField.

The output from the program (the 3 debug lines) is:

```
INSERT INTO [TestTable] ([IntField], [TextField]) VALUES (@p1, @p2)
UPDATE [TestTable] SET [IntField] = @p1, [TextField] = @p2 WHERE (([IntField] = @p3))
2
```

I have also created a trace on the SQL Server (using the Profiler), and this is the only statements executed:

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE 1=2
SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NO_BROWSETABLE ON; SET FMTONLY ON;SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE 1=2 SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NO_BROWSETABLE OFF;
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [TestTable] ([IntField], [TextField]) VALUES (@p1, @p2)',N'@p1 int,@p2 nvarchar(4)',@p1=4,@p2=N'loik'
```

So it seems that the code for some reason decides NOT to update the updated record in the SQL table, without raising an error, and this confuses me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to update a row I would think you need to retrieve that row and then update it. Assuming "intField" is unique you could do this.  This is C#, but it should give you the idea.

```
//find intField row    
DataRow[] Rows = MydataTable.Select("IntField=3");

Rows[0]["TextField"] = "poiuy";
MydataTable.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: In the real program my DataTable is read from a XML-file (serialized DataTable), and the DataAdapter is bound to a table in the SQL database (with the same Schema). And these tables can contain any number of fields, and a lot of records. That is one of the reasons why I would prefer not to have to load the SQL table into memory to be able to change some specific records. What confuses me is that the UpdateCommand statement looks correct, and the InsertStatement works as is should, and after the call to DataAdapter.Update the RowState of all the rows in the DataTable are Unchanged.

Comment: It's as if there is something that fails inside the DataAdapter.Update call.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126356/sqldataadapter-not-updating